# How can i update part of a list within a tuple? Also IndexError: list index out of range what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7

pnew to python and I am playing around with lists within tuples. I want to delete just the password not the Username, and update the password after the password has been deleted, however i tested the code to find out that it deletes the whole tuple and list within the tuple, then it gives me  IndexError: list index out of range....any help would be appreciated.

```
Users=[("Jim","password1"),("Bob","password2"),("Helen","password3"),("Beverly","blue")]

def changePassword():
    a=raw_input("Enter old password to continue:\n")

    for i in range(len(Users)):
        c,d=Users[i]
        if a==d:
            Users.remove(Users[i])
            print "Password deleted"
            print Users
    if a!=d:
        print"Incorrect"
        changePassword()
    a=raw_input("Enter new password:\n")
    for i in range(len(Users)):
        c,d=Users[i]
    if a==d:
        Users.append(Users[i])
        changePassword()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your function, unless I completely misunderstand its purpose, but let’s start with the `IndexError` you get.

This is the code where it happens:

```
for i in range(len(Users)):
    c,d=Users[i]
    if a==d:
        Users.remove(Users[i])
        print "Password deleted"
        print Users
```

So what happens here? You loop over the length of your list and if you matched the password then you remove the current user from the list. After that you continue iterating over the *previously calculated* length of the list. So, if you delete one item from the list, its length is reduced by one, *but* the for loop will still iterate over the old length (because `range(len(Users))` is immediately evaluated). So if you just deleted one user from the list, the last value for `i` will try to access an item that no longer exists in the list.

There is a related problem which would occur directly as a follow-up, and that is that you would skip elements in the loop. You are removing an item from the list but you are also advancing `i` just as you would if no item was removed. So when you remove, say, item `1`, then the *new* item `1` is the one that was previously `2`. So when you advance to `2`, you will have skipped that item.

So what can you do to fix this? Well, there are different methods. You could make a while loop instead and handle that indexing in a “classic” way (incrementing yourself and always checking the length in the while condition). You could also keep a second list to remember the items you are going to delete later (after the loop). However in your case, I think it might be a good idea to do something completely different.

From how I understood your function, you want to write something that allows you to change the password for a *single* user. So you enter the current password, then the new password and it will update the entry for the user in the list. This is not what is happening in your version as of now. What your function does is the following:

1. Ask for current password
2. Remove all users which have a matching password
3. Print "Incorrect" if the last user in the list did not have the entered password (it will only see the *last* value of `d`, so it will only check the very last user)
4. Ask for new password
5. Loop through the user list again and save only the last user (again, `c` and `d` will contain the last value after the loop)
6. If the last user had the same password as you have entered (why would you want to check that, you want to enter a *new* password), then append the very same user (because `i` again points at the last index in the list) to the list.

As you can see, there are some weird things going on, probably not intended. What you probably want to do instead is something like this:

1. Ask for the current password
2. Find the user for that password
3. Ask for the new password
4. Remove the old user from the list
5. Append a modified user to the list

So maybe something like this:

```
oldPassword = raw_input('Enter your old password to continue:\n') # 1
found = False
for name, password in Users:
    if password == oldPassword: # 2
        found = True
        break

if found:
    newPassword = raw_input('Enter new password:\n') # 3

    Users.remove((name, password))    # 4
    Users.append((name, newPassword)) # 5
else:
    print 'Incorrect password'
```

Comment: Works great! Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that a list of tuples is the best way to store user ids and passwords.
Maybe you could use a dictionary instead, that would look like this:

```
Passwords = {"Jim": "password1", "Bob": "password2", "Helen":"password3", "Beverly": "blue"}
```

This way you are sure that two different users will not have the same id.

Also, retrieving a user by its password is not a good idea, as several users may have the same
password. You should prompt for the user id first, or pass it as a parameter of your change password function. Something like this :

```
def changePassword(userId):
  input=raw_input("Enter old password to continue:\n")
  if input == Passwords[userId]:
    new_password = raw_input("Enter new password:\n")
    Passwords[userId] = new_password
  else:
    print "Wrong password"
    changePassword(userId)
```